# How in GitLab push changes to a remote branch that has diverged from non-master branch?

Tags: git, github, gitlab, branch

My branch `dev_match_test` is an update to the branch `origin/dev`.

I want to send my local changes of the `dev_match_test` branch to the remote repository,

such that the merge request to merge `dev_match_test` into `dev` could be later approved.

`git status` command tells that:

```
On branch dev_match_test
Your branch is ahead of 'origin/dev' by 22 commits.
    (use "git push" to publish your local commits)
```

but `git push` returns an error:

```
fatal: The upstream branch of your current branch does not match
the name of your current branch.  To push to the upstream branch
on the remote, use

    git push origin HEAD:dev

To push to the branch of the same name on the remote, use

    git push origin dev_match_test
```

Trying both suggested options gives no good:

```
git push origin HEAD:dev
```

returns an error

```
remote: GitLab: You are not allowed to push code to protected branches on this project.
```

I suspect it's because I'm trying to push changes to `dev` and I don't have permission for that. Instead I want to push to `dev_match_test`.

```
git push origin dev_match_test
```

just returns a message `Everything up-to-date` and does nothing.

**Question**: how to push local changes to the `dev_match_test` branch?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What might be easiest is to simply make a new branch from the current branch you're on, push to remote, then merge the new branch into dev.

1. Make a new branch from current branch:

`git checkout -b newBranchName`

2. Push to remote:

`git push -u origin newBranchName`

3. In GitLab, create a Merge Request for newBranchName into dev

Please note this does not fix your branch dev_match_test not properly pushing to remote. To solve that, more information would be helpful. I suspect that the branch dev_match_test is set up to track from origin/dev instead of origin/dev_match_test. If you could send the output of `git remote -v` (please hide URLs) that could be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

If you get the message "everything up-to-date", that means that all your local commits have already been pushed to the remote in the past.

Simply create a new merge request in GitLab and select the proper target (`dev`) and source (`dev_match_test`) branch and you should be all set.